# Is $xy y' = \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$ separable or non-separable?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find if this equation is separable or non-separable. If separable I need to find the general solution.

So far I've got

$$
\begin{align}
xy \frac{dy}{dx} &= \sqrt{ y^2 +1} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{\sqrt{ y^2 +1}}{xy} \\
dy &= \frac{\sqrt{ y^2 +1}}{xy} dx \\
ydy &= \frac{\sqrt{ y^2 +1}}{x} dx.
\end{align}
$$

I dont think this can be separated.

Comment: Yes, it is a Separable Equation. $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}~dy = \int \dfrac{1}{x}~dx$.

Comment: It is? Have I separated it correctly?

Comment: Divide both sides by $\sqrt{y^2+1}$

Comment: Well, to separate variables you must put the equation in the form $$f(y)dy=g(x)dx$$ So it is clearly possible in this case. Why you decided not to divide by $\sqrt{y^2+1}$ is quite a mystery, though.

Answer (score 1):

To "complete" the separation, you should bring the remaining $y$ terms to the left. You will get
$$ \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} dy = \frac{1}{x} dx.$$
In performing the integration, the left hand side is handled through $u$-substition and the right hand side gives $\ln x$.

Comment: for u substitution i would use y^2 +1 as u? and what would du be 2y dy?

Comment: @User1111111 yes

Comment: Umm... + C.  Sorry for the cheap shot!